# Images and manually added content are not displayed in out folder after using Static HTML Export in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, static

I completed building application on next.js and decided to use static HTML Export. First, I configured next.config.js and added

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
}
```

Second, I run `npm run build`. It created `out` folder, where I have static files and `index.html`.

But, when I open `index.html` it doesn't show me images, even though I manually edited `index.html` to add correct path for static files to be displayed.

> For instance, before editing: `/_next/static/chunks/webpack-60d328ea1049e7c2.js`, after editing: `./_next/static/chunks/webpack-60d328ea1049e7c2.js`. So, css files work, images don't.

What is more, I can't create any custom HTML elements in generated `index.html`. Well, actually, I can, but it just doesn't get displayed.

Only if I remove reference to some js files, it works, but, of course, this method also removes animations and some elements.

Besides, I turned off image optimization while exporting (it is required, by the way, for static HTML Export) and, of course, I added correct path to images.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also use tailwind css, maybe, this causes the issue?